# Как разделить блок на 30px и на всё оставшееся?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок. Нужно поделить на два. Один 30px, другой auto.

```html
<div>
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">

  </div>
</div>
```

Я решил проблему так:

```html
<table style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;">
<tr>
    <td style="width: auto; background-color: #abc">hвавфыавправi</td>
    <td style="width: 30px; background-color: #def">hii</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Интересно посмотреть без таблиц.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение на основе плавающих блоков.
1ый блок - 30px. Второй занимает всё оставшееся пространство, так как он `div` `(display: block;)`

```html
<div>
     <div style="float:left; width:30px; background-color:pink">h</div>
     <div style="background-color:olive">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, то, что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

flex:

```css
.right {
  width: 30px;
  flex-basis: 30px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: red;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
      Left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<table style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;">
<tr>
    <td style="width: calc(100% - 30px); background-color: #abc">hвавфыавправi</td>
    <td style="width: 30px; background-color: #def">hii</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: почему не 100% - 30px, а 100% -30%?

Comment: для таблицы достаточно указать ширину только для одной колонки, другая колонка займет всю оставшуюся ширину https://jsfiddle.net/wLbe8wea/1/

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатка, поправил